# socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('xxxxxx',data); not working on client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

client side code:

```
    var app = angular.module("msgApp", ['btford.socket-io']);
    app.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
         return socketFactory({
             prefix: '',
             ioSocket: io.connect('http://localhost:3000/messages')
         });

    });

    app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','socket',function($scope,socket){
        var room='asdf';
        socket.on('connect',function(){
            socket.emit('create',room);
        });

        socket.on('msg',function(data){
            console.log('received');
            $scope.msg=data;
        });

    }]);
```

server side code:

```
    'use strict';
    var app = require('express')();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000,err=>{
if(!err){
    console.log('app on 3k');
}
});

io.of('/orders').on('connection',(socket)=>{
socket.on('create',function(roomNo){
    console.log(roomNo);
    socket.join(roomNo);
    var roomNo = 'asdf';
socket.broadcast.to(roomNo).emit('msg','hi all');
})

})
```

I tried this connection is established and 'create' event is also working but broadcast to is not working,client is not getting messages,Please help me whether problem is with angular or in socket io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomNo).emit('msg','hi all');
```

You are telling the server to send to every client that is in `roomNo` except the current socket.  So, that message will not be sent to the current socket, but to other sockets in the room.  I set up a test app and verified this is the behavior.

If you want to broadcast to all sockets in a chat room, then use:

```
 io.to(roomNo).emit('msg','hi all');
```

---

In your server code, you should also remove this line since it is not needed and it conflicts with the argument by the same name:

```
var roomNo = 'asdf';
```